# no duplicates but still constraint violation error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have table in which a constraint has been set on a field called LoginId.While inserting a new row i am getting an error on this constratint associated with this field(LoginID)stating the below error.

The insert command is below:
Type 1 with sequence

```
insert into TemplateModule
(LoginID,MTtype, Startdate TypeId, TypeCase, MsgType, MsgLog, FileName,UserName, CrID, RegionaltypeId)
values 
(MODS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,3434,2843,2453,2392,435,2390,'pension.txt','rereee',454545,3434);
Failed with error
```

Type 2 without sequence a hardcoded value::

```
insert into TemplateModule
(LoginID,MTtype, Startdate TypeId, TypeCase, MsgType, MsgLog, FileName,UserName, CrID, RegionaltypeId)
values
(3453,3434,2843,2453,2392,435,2390,'pension.txt','rereee',454545,3434)
```

I crosschecked many times for duplicates.But nothing found.What could be the rootcause

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint error (LGN_INDEX)violated
```

Comment: how are you populating the value that you are trying to insert into that field?

Comment: ... and how are you crosschecking it?

Comment: The immediate cause is definitely two records with the same `LoginID`.  The root cause is that for some reason what *you* think is going into that column is not what the database gets.  So, what logging/tracing do you have or could you switch on?

Comment: Through the select command i crosscheked whether the value exist preivously.Supposing before doing an insertion with the values,I do a check with the select where condition containing those values.No rows will be reutrned which mad me confirm that no duplicates exist

Comment: Is this a multi-user system?  After your INSERT fails what values are in the table?  Are there any triggers on the `TemplateModule` table?  Do move statements fail - the sequence and the hardcoded one?

Comment: Triggers are there on the table for this field.yes Both fails.Yes its a multiuser system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a describe on LGN_INDEX on that table to make absolutely certain you are looking at the right column.  Is LGN_INDEX a constraint+index or just an index?  Try re-building your index to make sure it isn't corrupt.  Make sure you don't have any other constraints that might be interfering.

Second, perform a `SELECT MAX(LOGINID) FROM TEMPLATEMODULE` and compare that to the next sequence value to make sure your sequence isn't set lower than the maximum ID you are working with.

Third, check if you have any triggers on that table.

If none of these things work, try re-creating the table using just the schema.  Cross-load the data and try again.  There might be a configuration setting on that table that is causing the issue.  `CREATE TABLE MY_TEMP AS SELECT * FROM TEMPLATEMODULE`.

Comment: First and second mentioned by you is checked.Thirdly it has triggers.For the sequence creation the trigger was created.What could be the problem because of triggers

Comment: It all depends on what your trigger is doing.  Try disabling the trigger (or create a copy of the table without the trigger) and then perform your INSERT.  That will eliminate a piece of logic that can be interfering.

Comment: I am having insufficient previleges for creating a copy of the table.Only the dba can do that..Is there anyother options other than this??

Comment: Create the table in your own user schema (if you have privs for that).  If that works and you have a development environment, have your DBA disable the trigger and try it in the development environment.  If disabling the trigger fixes the problem, you'll need to debug your trigger.  Otherwise, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Yes.It works:)in the my_temp table..So trigger is the issue for sure.Thanks lot for the quick responses.Your alternatives(1,2,3) were so straight enough for me .

Comment: I am sorry to interrupt u back again.In this my_temp table the constraints set for the table are not copied.So if i try to insert the new row again with the duplicate values insertion happens:(

Comment: I'm confused, are you purposely inserting a duplicate or is it unique and throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

An Insert statement populating an Integer value (not in the table) to the Primary Key column.

The problem was a before trigger tied to a sequence. The next_val for the sequence was already present in the table.

The trigger fires, grabs the sequence number and fails with a Primary Key violation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue while importing from an excel file. I thought the file was free of duplicates until I tried removing duplicates in excel.

To find and remove duplicates in excel,

1. Select the data.   `Ctrl + a` should work.
2. Click `Data -> Remove Duplicates`
3. Select the fields that have the constraints in your database and click OK
4. Excel should remove any duplicate records based on the fields selected at step 3 above.

You should now be able to import records from the file into your db.